# Explain how non-blocking IO in Play works

Tags: multithreading, playframework, future

I found this article explain about non-blocking IO Play framework: https://engineering.linkedin.com/play/play-framework-async-io-without-thread-pool-and-callback-hell

Code example in that article

```
object ProxyController extends Controller {

  def proxy = Action {
    val responseFuture: Future[Response] = WS.url("http://example.com").get()

    Logger.info("Before map")
    val resultFuture: Future[Result] = responseFuture.map { resp =>
      Logger.info("Within map")
      // Create a Result that uses the http status, body, and content-type 
      // from the example.com Response
      Status(resp.status)(resp.body).as(resp.ahcResponse.getContentType)
    }
    Logger.info("After map")    

    Async(resultFuture)
}
```

The explaination from that article:

> Under the hood, Play uses a thread pool sized to one thread per CPU
>   core. One of these scarce threads, T1, executes the proxy action,
>   running through the code from top to bottom, except the contents of
>   the function passed to the map method, since that depends on a
>   non-blocking I/O call that has not yet completed. Once T1 returns the
>   AsyncResult, it moves on to process other requests. **Later on, when the
>   response from example.com is finally available**, another thread T2
>   (which may or may not be the same as T1) executes the function passed
>   to the map method. At no point were either of the threads blocked
>   waiting on the response from example.com.

I don't understand the highlighted in that paragraph. T1 has returned to thread pool and how the application keep track and receive the response from example.com then submit thread T2 to execute map function after that.

Please someone explain me this.

Comment: Your question is really "how does asynchronous IO work?", which you can read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O), and probably a lot of other places.

Comment: No. I mean here is how application listens and knows when example.com completes to submit thread T2. There is another thread is submitted to listen?

Comment: The answer is maybe. There are several ways this can be implemented by the JVM. If it is, it's not something you have access to.

Comment: This link answers my question http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/2015/09/03/asynchronous-and-non-blocking-io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of these scarce threads, T1, executes the proxy action, running through the code from top to bottom, except the contents of the function passed to the map method, since that depends on a non-blocking I/O call that has not yet completed.

At this point an object called a *future* has been created.

> Once T1 returns the AsyncResult, it moves on to process other requests.

The future sits in memory waiting to be fulfilled when some IO comes in. Meanwhile the thread T1 can process other requests.

> Later on, when the response from example.com is finally available,

When the response is available this will call some internal Play code which reads the response and changes the state of the *future* to give it a value. The moment the future gets a value it schedules its *map* code to run. This will run in some thread on thread pool, e.g. T2.

> another thread T2 (which may or may not be the same as T1) executes the function passed to the map method.
>
> At no point were either of the threads blocked waiting on the response from example.com.

Instead of waiting for IO by blocking a thread, Play secretly registered a callback so that when the IO is available it will fulfill a future. When the future is fulfilled it automatically calls the next part of the application code. This means the application code can wait (without using a thread) until the IO  is available.